# How to create this structure in mysql databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, e-commerce

I need to create such a structure, there is a category of products, each category stores its own information, for example, be entered phone information when selecting a phone category, computer information must be entered when selecting a computer category, **How to create this structure in a clean database? , how is it done in a real project?**

Comment: What are the attributes of phone information what are the attributes of computer information , in what way do the differ and how can you enforce the 'correct' attributes? Note this is your project you should be able to at least define these requirements yourself.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: that is, there are different categorie, smartphones category, Home appliances category,
My goal is to include this information when adding ads, for example, when selecting a phone category
Producer
Main camera
Screen
Number of cores
Screen type
NFC
Dimensions, 

Home Appliances - is when selecting the Washing Machines category This informations  
Producer
Drying
Number of programs
Unbalance control
Compression speed class

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a 'structure' in a DB you need to design your Entity-Relationship Diagram.

This means that you need to decide the Entities of your problem, these would be your tables later in the DB, the Relationships between the entities, these have multiple ways that can be depicted in the tables based mainly on their cardinality and then the properties of the entities, which will be the fields of the tables in your DB.

I think that you need to start from that, create the ER Diagram and then try to model it into the DB.

Comment: There is a structure, I just have a hard time doing this category, When adding an ad, when a Category is selected, I want information about the product of that category to come

Comment: If you already have the entities and the relationships of your DB schema, then add them to the question. This would make it easier for us to understand the problem and help you with it.